# Algebraic Manipulation for extracting a simplified representation

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

I am currently working on simplifying a series of equations to have a more simplified formula to be used in scripting software (as I need to process this for a wide variety of inputs). It mainly requires some algebraic manipulations, but I struggle finding a good approach which makes it easier to read/implement rather then harder. All constants are known with the exception of $ E_{met}$
The goal is to extract a formula for $ E_{met}$ using the formula's below:

$$
E_{fc}I_{fc} = E_{waf}I_{waf}+E_{waf}A_{waf}a_{1}^2+E_{met}I_{met}+E_{met}A_{met}a_{2}^2
$$
$$
a_{2}=\frac{E_{waf}A_{waf}(T_{total})}{2(E_{waf}A_{waf}+E_{met}A_{met})}
$$
$$
a_{1}=\frac{T_{total}}{2}-a_{2}
$$

At some point I am always stuck with the variable in the denominator and fail to get it out. Thanks for any input in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=E_{met}.$ Your main equation, after subtarcting $E_{fc}I_{fc}$ (and eliminating $a_1$ thanks to the third equation) is of the form
$$0=a+b\left(\frac t2-a_2\right)^2+xc+xda_2^2.$$
Replacing $a_2$ by $\frac{bt}{2(b+xd)}$ (according to your second equation) and multiplying by $4(b+xd)^2,$ this equation becomes
$$0=4(a+xc)(b+xd)^2+b\left(t(b+xd)-bt\right)^2+xdb^2t^2$$
i.e. after simplification:
$$0=4(a+xc)(b+xd)+bdt^2x.$$
This is a quadratic equation which I think you will be able to solve.

Comment: Hi Anne, thanks for this! An elegant way of dealing with it by representing common factors as letters. One thing which I do not get (maybe stupid question) is why you can simply subtract $E_{fc}I_{fc}$ from the equation without also subtracting it on other side of the equation? I do not see it appearing on the right side of the equation or am I missing something?

Comment: I subtracted on both sides! My $a$ is $E_{waf}I_{waf}-E_{fc}I_{fc}.$

Comment: Hi Anne, thanks for clarifying this! I completely overlooked that option!